# How to think about and select variables for the zero-inflated part of the ZINB

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

The question of modeling the zero-inflated part of a negative binomial mixed effects model is a thorn in my side. I've read a lot of articles and blogs and it seems to be an issue that is largely glossed over, perhaps due to the fact the choice about the zero-inflated part of the model is very specific to each research question. However, some articles/blogs emphasize that the zero-inflated part intends to model structural zeros and they select variables very narrowly. Others discuss how it is a mixture of sampling and structural zeros, and model both the count and zero inflated parts the same way. However, with zero-inflated assumed to be a mixture of structural and sampling zeros,   why not just generally model both sides the same way? Is it more about parsimony? How do you chose which variables to include?